# How can I generate multiple textInput component with using "each" and how I can changed the state with combination of all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want a develop text based word game. Every level word's length will change.I will split every letter into one box and my matrix also changed like (10 words , length :10 => 10x10 matrix). How can I generate a multiple textInput component with this variables. I want to create something look like that imgur.com/a/6Dtjy2g. Every row include one word and every box include the one letter also. I wanted to fill the every box and update my state, in the end will check it with the answer.

Comment: can you be more specifics? provide some code for example?

Comment: I want a create something look like that https://imgur.com/a/6Dtjy2g . Every row include one word and every box include one letter and this boxes component can changed the length of words. When user type the boxes I wanted to change my state and controle it after complete the typing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, to render the view as you want, your code should look like below. About the state design, it depends much on your game logic, you can share it more by editing your question.

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

class Board extends React.Component {
  state = { board: [
            "wordword01", "wordword02", "wordword03", "wordword04", "wordword05",
            "wordword06", "wordword07", "wordword08", "wordword09", "wordword10"
  ]};

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.board.map(word => (
          <TextInput defaultValue={word}/>
        ))}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default Board;
```